# Add legend to Python scatter plot with variable size

Tags: python, plot, scatter

I have a scatter plot in which the greater the frequency of some numeric value, the greater the size of the respective point in the scatter plot.

I need to add a legend with some referential sizes and its respective value.

An excerpt from the code:

```
for key in counter.keys():
    pl.scatter(count, key, s=counter[key]*15, color=next(colors))
```

Here is a similar graph that has the kind of legend I want:
http://revolution-computing.typepad.com/.a/6a010534b1db25970b01348974ea77970c-500wi

Comment: Your explanation and code is not nearly enough to explain what you want to do.  Please post a small code snippet that actually illustrates what you want, what you've tried and what is not working.

Comment: What plotting module are you using? What kind of output does it produce?

Comment: I am using matplotlib. What do you mean by "what kind of output"?